# expanded and collapsed not read in jaws+chrome for a accordian button but working fine in nvda+firefox

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

```html
<div class="ph-accordian-section ph-section-control" role="listitem">
                <button aria-label="" aria-expanded="false" key-aria-label="accFaq1AriaLabelText"
                    data-ph-tevent-attr-trait13="What information should I include?" class="ph-accordian-title"
                    ref="acc1" accordin-num="accordian1" click.delegate="showContent(acc1)">
                    <ppc-content key="whatIncludeAccTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur?</ppc-content>
                    <i class="iconPointer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="ph-accordian-content" accordin-num="accordian1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="acc-content">
                        <ppc-content key="accFaq1whatIncludeDescText">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nisi est, vulputate eget
                            lacinia ac, convallis in arcu. Aenean euismod accumsan rutrum. In sollicitudin massa sit
                            amet leo suscipit, ut maximus augue gravida. Quisque eu molestie dui. Maecenas volutpat
                            porta nisi sit amet consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus.
                        </ppc-content>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i have added code as above it is working fine in nvda+ff but not reading expanded and collapsed in jaws+chrome
i have compared with http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/code/accordions/
and remodelled the code like as below

```html
<li class="ph-accordian-section ph-section-control" role="listitem">
            <button aria-controls="accordian1" aria-label="" aria-expanded="false" key-aria-label="accFaq1AriaLabelText"
                data-ph-tevent-attr-trait13="What information should I include?" class="ph-accordian-title"
                ref="acc1" accordin-num="accordian1" click.delegate="showContent(acc1)" data-ol-has-click-handler>
                <ppc-content key="whatIncludeAccTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur?</ppc-content>
                <i class="iconPointer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="ph-accordian-content" accordin-num="accordian1" aria-hidden="true" id="accordian1">
                <div class="acc-content">
                    <ppc-content key="accFaq1whatIncludeDescText">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nisi est, vulputate eget
                        lacinia ac, convallis in arcu. Aenean euismod accumsan rutrum. In sollicitudin massa sit
                        amet leo suscipit, ut maximus augue gravida. Quisque eu molestie dui. Maecenas volutpat
                        porta nisi sit amet consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus.
                    </ppc-content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Still in jaws+chrome it is not announcing expanded or collapsed even though aria-expanded is updating properly...
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Tough to tell because you need before and after code for when the button is collapsed then expanded. Your two code examples are two different layouts. Unrelated, but why is aria-label blank? You fill it in dynamically? To make your question simpler, your code example can leave off `class`, `data-`, `ref`, and non-html attributes like `key-aria-label`, `accordin-num`, `key`, etc.

Comment: Could you provide a working example in CodePen or another online editor? There's no way of telling why JAWS & Chrome aren't announcing the `aria-expanded` state of your accordion from looking at your code because, as slugolicious says, there's no before and after code example.

Answer (score 0):

The example link you shared works fine with both JAWS + Chrome and NVDA + Firefox.
The example code looks fine however unable to determine as the expanded state will be added based on the user action. If you can share any working prototype it can be tested.
Please refer 3.1 Accordion from the following link and example has source code as well.
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion

Note: If it is an accordion with multiple expandable content then better to go for accordion pattern in which the button is a child element of heading tag. If this is a single button then go for "3.10 disclosure" pattern.
Please state the version of your JAWS and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can fix it.

1. reset the focus on the click element.
2. update the aria-expanded=true/false on setTimeout callback.

Also, please find the aria-expand example on below reference url:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).